# Importing CVS data to Angel LMS

Tags: cvs

I have problems importing gradesheet cvs file to angel LMS. It does not show 
nothing when i tried to import it. Please guide me what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

go into the sql query manager, select from the table you want to import into, mimic those fields in your csv file, then add your data and follow these steps

go to admin console 
go to the tools tab 
click on text import wizard 
select your file 
click upload 
click continue if your options look right 
review your columns and set defaults 
click continue 
select the table you want to import into